# using fork() , execlp() and dup2()

Tags: c, pipe, fork, file-descriptor, dup2

###### I am writing a C program which will run Linux commands, like:

```
ls -al | grep "main" | sort
```

I used just the children to do that.  *(it work when I use the parent to execute the last one but I want to use just the children )*

I have a problem that is the last fork execute before the second fork.
and that will run this command `ls -al | sort | grep "main"` 
in  this example the result is the same but with others is wrong.

###### how can I wait the second fork in the last fork ?.

### code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2],fd1[2];

    pipe(fd);pipe(fd1);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[READ]);close(fd1[WRITE]);close(fd[READ]);
        printf("i'm the child used for ls \n");
        dup2(fd[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[WRITE]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            close(fd1[READ]);close(fd[WRITE]);
            printf("i'm in the second child, which will be used to run grep\n");
            dup2(fd[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[READ]);
            close(fd1[READ]);close(fd[WRITE]);
            dup2(fd1[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd1[WRITE]);
            execlp("grep", "grep", "main", NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                /* code */
                close(fd[READ]);close(fd[WRITE]);close(fd1[WRITE]);
                printf("i'm in the third child, which will be used to run (sort)\n");
                dup2(fd1[READ], STDIN_FILENO);
                close(fd1[READ]);
                execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look more carefully at which file descriptors you are closing and where.  Especially in your setup for the child running the `grep` command.

Comment: Also, check the return values of your function calls. If you did so consistently (and reported on the results appropriately) then the nature of the issue would already be clear to you.

Comment: how can I wait for the child running the grep command in the child running sort command

Comment: the last child print just the message before the child running the grep command

Comment: Re-read my previous comments.  Get your pipes set up correctly and everything will start working.

Comment: it work but it execute the ( ls -al | sort | grep "main" ) instead of what we want

Comment: That is a matter of data flow -- which is entirely to do with how the pipes are set up -- not a matter of execution order of the children.  Generally speaking, the processes in a pipeline can and *must* run concurrently.  So again, get your pipes right.